# why does sharePoint not allow any form tag in the code.I am trying to add a form in there but gives me error saying <form> tag not allowed

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 
    Name:*      <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br />
    Email:*     <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <br />
    Comments:*  <br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="comment">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:left;" />
</form>
```

Can you identify the problem?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint is built on ASP.NET. Part of the pattern of ASP.NET pages is that the whole page behaves a form and has a form as the top level element under body. As such you can't embed a form within a form. Depending on what you want to do with the HTML fields you can embed input fields or use a custom WebPart.

Comment: Your 100% correct buddy.The form inputs show fine but when i submit the form after providing the ask info it wont get submit .i have also added validation to it which wont work either.Im trying to get the given info from the user to be send the email i provide.

Comment: @DavinderpalSingh The solution is to not use an HTML form element. Since you're working with SharePoint, why not just collect the information in a SharePoint list? You can then use SharePoint designer to insert a list form onto a page and collect the fields of info as appropriate.

Comment: @Thriggle because html forms can be easily custom-made and allow complex decision-tree forms (using `disabled` `fieldset`s for example.